# Kotlin noArg plugin not recognised by IntelliJ

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am not sure if I've missed a config or stumbled upon a bug. I am using IntelliJ to build a Kotlin Spring Boot application with JPA and would like to use Kotlin noArg plugin to reduce boilerplate in Entities.

With the build.gradle.kts below my application compiles OK but IntellJ underlines my Entity with error `Class 'User' should have [public, protected] no-arg constructor`.

Is there something I can set up in IntelliJ or build.gradle to make the error disappear?

System specs:

- Windows 11 + WSL
- IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.1 (Ultimate Edition)
- Kotlin plugin 213-1.6.10-release-944-IJ6461.79

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.6.4"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.noarg") version "1.6.10"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.10"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.6.10"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.6.10"
}

group = "XXXXXX"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_16

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    runtimeOnly("com.h2database:h2")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
}

noArg {
    annotation("javax.persistence.Entity")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "16"
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yeah, sometimes IntelliJ gets out of sync. Have you tried running `gradle clean build`? Invalidating caches? Restarting IntelliJ or your PC? Hitting the 'reload Gradle' button? Or anything else?

Comment: Yes tried all that, several times :-(

Comment: Hm, okay. Does it happen on any other machine? You can try removing the `noArg { }` config and the `id(kotlin.plugin,noarg)` - they're redundant, as `kotlin(plugin.jpa)` applies the same config automatically.

Comment: Haven't tried on a different machine so far. Tried your suggestion to remove the plugin in build.gradle to no avail, sadly. Also updated my IDE and the Kotlin plugin to the latest versions and the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it's a bug in IntelliJ running on WSL-based project.

I'm tracking the bug here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-21314/ and will update the answer once resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but with my Maven project. The thing was in `<executions>` block. Maybe IDEA doesn't understand such complex configs yet. I removed it and kept this simple config.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <sourceDirs>
            <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
            <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDir>
        </sourceDirs>
        <compilerPlugins>
            <plugin>jpa</plugin>
            <plugin>all-open</plugin>
            <plugin>spring</plugin>
        </compilerPlugins>
        <pluginOptions>
            <option>all-open:annotation=javax.persistence.Entity</option>
            <option>all-open:annotation=javax.persistence.Embeddable</option>
            <option>all-open:annotation=javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass</option>
        </pluginOptions>
        <args>
            <!-- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/boot-features-kotlin.html#boot-features-kotlin-null-safety -->
            <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
        </args>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to reload the project, for me it worked in a maven project.

Answer (score 0):

if you use new version java, javax changed to jakarta

> Java Persistence API (JPA), in 2019 renamed to Jakarta Persistence

so you may need to configure your pom.xml file like this

```
             <configuration>
                <compilerPlugins>
                    <plugin>spring</plugin>
                    <plugin>jpa</plugin>
                    <plugin>no-arg</plugin>
                </compilerPlugins>
                <pluginOptions>
                    <option>no-arg:annotation=jakarta.persistence.Entity</option>
                </pluginOptions>
                <jvmTarget>17</jvmTarget>
            </configuration>
```

and plugin dependencies like this

```
<dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
                    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue after upgrading my Spring Boot Kotlin project to v3.

You need to add the following allOpen extension to build.gradle.kts:

```
allOpen {
    annotation("jakarta.persistence.Entity")
    annotation("jakarta.persistence.Embeddable")
    annotation("jakarta.persistence.MappedSuperclass")
}
```

Reference "Persistence with JPA" section in:

https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-kotlin/